# php - regex replacing strings with braces and quotes

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, notepad++

I see a lot of questions here regarding regex in general , but the problem is that they are usually (like mine) quite localized, and difficult to deduct if one is not a regex expert ..

My string involves characters like quotes and braces , which are quite known for making regex more difficult.

I would like to know the expression strings (search, replace) I need in order to perform this task.

in other words , in :

```
 ereg_replace (string pattern, string replacement, string subject)
```

I will need the `string pattern` and `string replacement` expressions.

my string is

```
array('val' => 'something', 'label' => 'someword'),
```

I need to change the last part :

```
'label' => 'someword'),
```

to

```
'label' => __('someword','anotherstring')),
```

I will be using php for that , but I would also like to test it ( and also use in other cases) with Notepad ++ . ( I do not know if it actually changes something regarding the search and replace strings ).

Note that the string `someword` can also be `SomeWord` or `SOMEWORD` or even `Some word` or `Some_Word` on cases, meaning it can contain spaces, underscores or actually almost any character from within...)

**Edit I :** forgot to mantion that the `__()` part is of course wordpress textdomain function for translations . e.g. `__('string','texdomain')`

**Edit II :**

I am sorry if I come off too exigent or demanding in the comments , I really do try to **UNDERSTAND** and not only copy-paste a solution that might not work for me in other cases ..
:-)

**Edit III :**

By the help of [THIS](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) tool , I understood that my basic misunderstanding is the possibility to use VARIABLES inside regex .
The `$1` is actually all I needed for better understanding .

the (incredibly simple) pattern that will work also in notepad++

```
Pattern: 'label' => ('.*')

Replace: 'label' => __(\1,'textdomain')
```

(In notepad++ it is called Tag Region (not var) and it is marked as `\1`

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you want, 'label' => 'someword'), to 
'label' => __('someword','anotherstring')) ?

Comment: @Akam - yes .. but the `someword` part is an unknown string , not literally `someword`. it can be anything .. the `anotherstring` part however is a fixed string .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Regex-es are not very flexible. For given input and output presented in your question [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dxXTId) will give you desired result. Regex pattern is: `'label' => ('.*')` If all you need is quick replacement with IDE this is enough.

Comment: Will `'label' => '*'` basically be the pattern you are trying to match against (i.e. are you always triyng to replace the value to the label key)?

Comment: @MikeBrant - actually I want to wrap that value with __('originalvalue','anotherstring')

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I forgot to mention that [`ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) is deprecated.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I understand what the replacement consists of, I was trying to verify what the actual matching criteria are.

Comment: @MikeBrant , sorry for misunderstanding, than the answer is yes, `'label' => '*'` would be the matching criteria, or maybe `'label' => '*'),`

Comment: @PLB your example seems to work .. can you elaborate on that with some simple explanation in order to better understand ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Yes, sure. This pattern matches following part from a string: 'label' => _any character between `'`_ Part of pattern in braces will group _any character between `'`_ that can be later accessed with `$1`.

Comment: @PLB thanks,  it might be helpful also to others if you will add it as an answer ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Yes, you're right. I'll post it as an answer. I was not sure what your needs were, that's why I've commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will always be looking for the `label` key, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$pattern = "/array\((.*), 'label' => '(.*)'/U";
$added_string = 'anotherstring';
$replacement = 'array($1, ' . "'label' => __('" . '$2' . "','$added_string'";
$final_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $original_string);
```

Comment: so in terms of PURE regex, what would be the search pattern and what would be the replacement ? (I am sorry but when it comes to regex some characters like braces, variables, dollar signs and quotes are confusing, becasue I never trust myself know if they are part of the regex or part of the programming language (like variables).

Comment: The whole `$pattern` shown IS the regex. `$replacement` is not a regex, however it does use backreferences `$1` and `$2` to the captured subpatterns from the regex.  The `$added_string` part in replacement is just a variable that contains the other string that needs to be added. If this is a constant value, you could just as easily omit the use of a variable here. Note that it is important to not use double quotes around area of string where backreferences are noted (unless you want to use `\\1` syntax for backreference.

Comment: ok, and the first  '/' in $pattern is just escaping, or is it part of the regex expression ?

Comment: the first and last forward slash are just pattern delimiters you can really use almost any matching characters as delimiters.  `/` is most commonly used except in cases where you know `/` will be part of the pattern, then you might see `~` or `#` commonly used such that one would not need to escape the delimiter in the pattern itself.

Comment: You really ought to take time reading up on proper use of regex at it is a very powerful tool to have in one's toolchest. Any reasonably experienced developer should be expected to at least have basic regex skills.

Comment: +1 on that , Really . I know, It just seems sooo confusing at start . I am basically a web design person, not a hardcore programmer (although I do manage to do pretty much all I need with PHP - my other skills like simple js syntax or regex are painfully lacking )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Understandable coming from that background. Regex is really not some mystical things so good that you are trying to figure it out a bit.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen [Here's](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) great tool. Play around with it. There's brief explanation what some patterns are doing. Put them together and you'll almost always get what you need. Everything complex consists of simple parts. :)

Comment: @PLB - thanks, looks great, I already found some ready made snippets over there (in community) - Look like a gret tool to learn !

Answer (score 1):

For given inputs and outputs in question pattern: `'label' => ('.*')` is enough to match strings and perform replacement. This pattern matches following part from a string: 'label' => *any character between `'`* . Part of pattern in braces will group *any character between `'`* that can be later accessed with `$1`. E.g.:

```
$str = "array('val' => 'something', 'label' => 'some testing string_with\$specialchars\/'),";
$str = preg_replace('/\'label\' => (\'.*\')/', '\'label\' => __($1, \'some other string\')', $str);
echo $str;
//Outputs:
//   array('val' => 'something', 'label' => __('some testing string_with$specialchars\/', 'some other string')),
```

Comment: thanks again - the link you posted http://codepad.viper-7.com/dxXTId demonstrates and works well (reposted for future ref by people who will read this answer )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen You're welcome. I'm glad that I could help you. ;)

Comment: @ see my last edit , actually, what was missing for my understanding was the '$1' variable .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$strings = array('some word', 'some Word', 'SOMEword', 'SOmE_Word', 'sOmE_ WOrd');
$pattern = '/([a-z]+)([^a-z]*)([a-z]+)/i';
foreach($strings as $v){
 echo preg_replace($pattern, 'otherword', $v)."<br>";
}
?>
```

output:

```
otherword
otherword
otherword
otherword
otherword
```

EDIT:

```
$pattern = "/('label'\s=>\s')(([a-z]+)([^a-z]*)([a-z]+))('\),)/i";
$otherword = 'otherword';
$replacement = "'label' => __('$2','$otherword')),";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "'label' => 'someword'),");
```

output:

'label' => __('someword','otherword')),

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4ip-20f)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe this will only make a simple replacement, not a wrapping of a function . also, it does not involve all the troublemakers like `(` `,` `)` and `=`

Comment: can you provide list of matching words (patterns) with list of replacements clearly?